# Using a function pointer array to call a method of a class

Tags: c++, oop, function-pointers

I would like to write a program in C++ which contains an array of function pointers.
Here is the code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   class MyClass {
   int a, b;
   public:
   MyClass(int i, int j) : a(i), b(j) {}
   int add() { return a + b; }
   int sub() { return a - b; }
 };

void func(int (MyClass::* funcPtr[])(), MyClass& a, int i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    funcPtr[i] = &MyClass::add;
    funcPtr;
  }

  if (i == 1) {
    funcPtr[i] = &MyClass::sub;
    funcPtr;
}
cout << " Result: " << (a.*funcPtr[i])() << endl;
}

int main(){
  int auswahl = 0;
  int i = 4, j = 5;

  cout << "Which function? [0]-Add [1]-Substract\n";
  cin >> select;
  
  MyClass a(i,j);
  func(NULL, a, select);
}
```

After playing around a lot I got the program to compile successfully. But it throws "Write Access Violation" on running.

The problem seems to be related to:

```
funcPtr[i] = &MyClass::add;
funcPtr[i] = &MyClass::sub;
```

It'd be very nice, if you could help me solve the problem.

Thank you so much and have a happy time!

Comment: `funcPtr` is `NULL`, there is no array in your code

Comment: It's related to you attempting to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: well the array pointer is null, what did you expect that line to do?

Answer (score 0):

As you pass `NULL` or `nullptr` in your function, so this line:

```
funcPtr[i] = &MyClass::add;
```

Is writing at index `i` into a null array!

You'd have to provide an array for your function to write into:

```
 MyClass a(i,j);
 int (MyClass::* funcPtr[2])();
 func(funcPtr, a, select);
```

Note that using `std::array` instead of c-style array would avoid this problem, since they are not nullable:

```
void func(std::array<int (MyClass::*)(), 2> funcPtr, MyClass& a, int i) {
    // ...
}

// ...

std::array<int (MyClass::*)(), 2> funcPtr;
func(funcPtr /* cannot pass null */, a, i);
```

Comment: Alright! Thanks everyone. I didn't know that passing NULL as an argument would end up making a null-pointer. I assumed that the function pointer was made in "MyClass". Below I wrote "NULL" because I didn't have an argument to Pass to the function pointer. From Java I got the habit to pass something like NULL when I don't want to pass anything.

Comment: @SamuilIliev Now you know that the computer does exactly what you tell it to, even when it doesn't make sense... Speaking of which, even if your program doesn't crash any more, it still doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Yeah, indeed :D